# Как в unity создать вкладку с отображением сетки

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui, unity3d-editor, customeditor

Я создаю пиксельную игру и для упрощения создания уровней (из тайлов) я бы хотел создать свою вкладку для автоматической генерации уровней по моей разметке

То есть, я создаю новую вкладку (желательно в стандартных (на любой unity'вской вкладке три точки > Add Tab > Моя Вкладка) а не в Window или любой другой)
[image]
И там должна отобразиться сетка как в Scene на которой я могу мышкой менять цвета клеточек и при нажатии кнопки генерировать должен сгенерироваться уровень из тайлов (но это я сам реализую)

Например я открываю любую мини-вкладку и в ней выбираю текущий цвет/теги и тд (как в Scene > три точки > Overlays > мини-вкладка (например в первой настройка самой сетки, во второй настройка цветов/тегов, в третьей настройка спрайтов и привязка сторон к тегам  + кнопкой генерировать и тд)
[image]
Я уже почитал и понял что можно через EditorWindow но вот как сделать сами мини-вкладки и клетки как в сцене (с масштабированием и всем таким) я не особо понял у меня только наподобие второго инспектрра получается и ни сколько на вкладку сцены не похоже

Comment: ладно, пойду пока что дальше ChatGPT и браузер мучить